# java best practices in matrix/vector library

Tags: java, coding-style, vector

i have to write a simple vector/matrix library for a small geometry related project i'm working on.  here's what i'm wondering.

when doing mathematical operations on vectors in a java environment, is it better practice to return a new instance of a vector or modify the state of the original.

i've seen it back and forth and would just like to get a majority input.

certain people say that the vectors should be immutable and static methods should be used to create new ones, others say that they should be mutable and normal methods should be used to modify their state.  i've seen it in some cases where the object is immutable and normal methods are called which returns a new vector from the object without changing the state - this seems a little off to me.

i would just like to get a feel for if there is any best practice for this - i imagine it's something that's been done a million times and am really just wondering if there's a standard way to do this.

i noticed the apache commons math library returns a new vector every time from the original.

Comment: My own gut tells me to make vectors immutable, but my official answer is "it all depends", including how and where you're going to use them. For instance, if I were using them inside of some graphics routine, I'd perhaps want mutable objects so as to not have the overhead of having to create new objects frequently (if profiling showed this to be a potential problem).

Comment: I think I need some clarification. When you say "vector" do you mean a Java "Vector" (collection of Objects) or are you referring to a mathematical construct relative to direction and distance?

Comment: @John: Since he's discussing matrices in the same breath and discussing the mathematics of vectors, I think it's safe to assume he's referring to the mathematical concept of vector and not the core Vector class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How important is performance going to be? Is vector arithmetic going to be a large component so that it affects the performance of overall system?

If it is not and there is going to be lot of concurrency then immutable vectors will be useful because they reduce concurrency issues.

If there are lot of mutations on vectors then the overhead of new objects that immutable vectors will require will become significant and it may be better to have mutable vectors and do the concurrency the hard way.

Comment: Thanks @Hovercraft, our opinions seem to be identical. Good to know that there are others that think immutable objects are not always practical :)

Comment: it makes more sense in this case to make the vector immutable - but the thing i'm really wondering i guess is does it make sense to have a class that has private final fields, a constructor, then methods along the lines of add and subtract that return new Vector objects and don't alter the state of the instance you're calling it upon - this is currently what i have implemented it just seems a little off every time i say something like Vec2D sum = a.plus(b), it seems like reading that a.plus(b) should alter a. maybe my ocd is just getting to me.

Comment: The one thing i was thinking is like how java.lang.Math does its `pow` and `sqrt` by passing in params, but then when i actually implement it and use it in code it looks terrible to say something along the lines of `Vec2D sum = Vec2D.add(a, b);`, any of them will work i suppose i just wonder if there's a standard way people have done it

Comment: To me `sum = a.plus(b)` shows it will not alter `a`, else it would have been `a.add(b); // no assignment`. I would like to think others have decided whether to take the immutable objects or mutating operations route depending on the concerns I list above but I cannot claim to know.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. Generally speaking, immutability is better.

First and foremost, it is automatically threadsafe. It is easier to maintain and test.

That said, sometimes you need speed where creating new instances will take too much time.

(Note: If you're not 100% positive you need that amount of speed, you don't need it. Think high-frequency trading and real-time math-intensive applications. And even though, you should go simple first, and optimize later.)

As for static vs normal methods, following good OOP principles, you shouldn't have static methods. To create new vectors/matrices you can use the constructor.

Next, what's your backing structure? Your best bet is probably single-dimensional arrays of doubles for vectors and multi-dimensional arrays of doubles for matrices. This at least lets you stay relatively quick by using primitive objects.

If you get to the point that you need even more performance, you can add modifiers on your Vector/Matrix that can change the backing data. You could even decide that the dimensions are immutable but the contents are mutable which would give you some other safeties as well.

Comment: +1 I wish the downvoter had explained why. I think this is a nice answer.

Comment: Seconded. Both of us have more or less the same answer.

Comment: Agree. Except that you are leaning towards immutable objects. I got chided recently for not referring to them, so I am perhaps a little miffed at people saying they are the silver bullet of concurrency.

Comment: Downvote was for dogma:  "following good OOP principles, you shouldn't have static methods"  This removes any possibility of providing static methods for instantiation that shield the types returned, and other legitimate uses for static methods, such as Apache Commons' libraries (StringUtils, etc).